# Passing an object as a parameter into a sub-class in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I've been trying to comprehend python's implementation of OOP.

Essentially I need something which is a superclass that defines some global attributes that al l other classes use as input for their methods. Eg:

This is how i thought it should be done:

```
class One():
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

class Two(One):
     def __init__(self, name):    # name from class one...
         One.__init__(self, name)          
     def method_using_name_from_one(self, name_from_one):
         return name_from_one
```

I guess that I could do this by just declaring all the methods in class `Two` as in methods of class one, but I'd much prefer to have them separated. So to recap: I want the parameters for the method in class two to use the attributes declared in class `One`. So essentially I want to pass in an instantiated object as the parameter arguments for class `Two` methods.

Comment: Are you expecting `self` to not have the attributes from class 1 in class 2's methods? What's wrong with just using `self.name`?

Comment: I'm extremely confused by what you're not understanding.  You can use `self.name` in methods inside of class `Two`

Comment: The parameter `name_from_one` seems like a code smell to me. If it is to be passed a value as an argument, it's not really "from One". If you want to use the value that was assigned to the `name` attribute of your instance of `Two` in the chained constructor, use `self.name`, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
class Two(One):
```

One isn't a parameter of `class Two`. That means class Two inherits from class One. In other words, unless you override a method, it gets everything class One has. **edit: When I say this, I mean parameters and functions, I don't mean an instance of the class.** Since you have:

```
def __init__(self, name):    # name from class one...
    One.__init__(self, name)
```

self.name is in `class Two.` In other words, you could just say...

```
 def method_using_name_from_one(self):
     return self.name
```

One thing I would suggest is changing your class One declaration to:

```
 class One(object):
```

This means it inherits from object, it doesn't mean it's getting passed an object :)
Is this what you meant? Maybe I didn't understand correctly.

If you want the name parameter from `One,` you could say

```
 def method_using_name_from_one(self, oneInstance):
     return oneInstance.name
```

Comment: ah right of course. Though I don't think i've been very clear. I essentially wanted class two to have methods that require an instance of class one as an "parameter" input. You can do such in java by in effect declaring a 'type' (eg how even primitive types are classes...) and was wondering how to do similar in python.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean in Java? I'm not following exactly. Anyway, isn't that what my last example does?